# Passing array instead of callback in array_filter

Tags: php

I'm looking at this example [array_filter comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#89384) and he passes an argument to array_filter as

```
array_filter($subject, array(new array_ereg("image[0-9]{3}\.png"), 'ereg')
```

How is it that the callback accepts an array with multiple arguments one of them being the actual callback function

Comment: As an aside, `ereg` functions are deprecated, and you should avoid using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP it is possible to represent a [`callable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) using an array in the following format.

`array($object, 'methodName')`

The documentation itself states:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

It is quite common to see this used with the `$this` variable inside objects.

In your example, the first element of the array is created with `new`, and is the **instantiated** object required, and `ereg` is the method.

Answer (score 1):

The [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions expects a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for it's second parameter.
PHP understands an `array($instance, 'methodname')` as callable for instance methods, and `array('classname', 'staticmethodname')` for static methods (or simple `'classname::staticmethod'` since version 5.2.3 .

Answer (score 0):

To extend other answers. In PHP >= 5.3, we can use closures.

```
$numbers = range(1,10);
$newNumbers = array_filter($numbers, function($value) {
    return ($value & 1) === false;
});
// $newNumbers now contains only even integers. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PHP: Callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) page.

When an array is specified for a **callable** parameter, you are specifying an **object** and a **method** of that object. For example:

```
$object = new MyClass();
array_filter($input, array($object, 'myClassMethod'));
```

In the example you provided:

```
array_filter($subject, array(new array_ereg("image[0-9]{3}\.png"), 'ereg');
```

The new instance of **array_ereg** is the *object* and **ereg** is the *method* of the array_ereg class.